# Design issue: client side or server side?

Tags: javascript, python, ruby

Whenever there is dilemma to do a particular task, which can be accomplished either by client side code or by using a server code, which should be preferred?

For example:

I can iterate through a javascript object and construct a string and then send it to server, or should i send the javascript object and process it in the server?

My views: whenever I come across this situation I use the client side code as it reduces the computation load on server.

What has to be done in such a situation? Which is the right approach?

Comment: broad question I'd say. It really depends on the task itself.

Comment: You can't expect a single answer for all cases "where there is a dilemma". If there were a single answer, the dilemma wouldn't exist.

Comment: Keep in mind that client side code is exposed to any who want to see it, plus it can be easily manipulated.

Comment: Define "right".  What is **most** important?  If "right" means to reduce computation load on the server, then right is Javascript.  If "right" means to make the most use of Oracle-licensed software, the right is to write PL/SQL scripts.  What do you think you mean by "right"?

Comment: @S.Lott which is the right approach when i am using open-source software ?.. I have never worked in an company, so i wanted to know how experienced guys like you would make a decision..

Comment: @vireshas: Define "right". That's the most important thing.  Read the other comments: You can't expect a single answer for all cases "where there is a dilemma". If there were a single answer, the dilemma wouldn't exist.  Using "open source software" is only one small part of the dilemma.  You have to write down all the things that are important and make a difficult decision every single time.

Comment: @Lott  sir , can you please edit the question so that i get more relevant answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(This answer assumes a web programming context)

I personally put a lot of front-end logic in Javascript running on the client side, because it makes things very responsive, even for people with a slow connection. This also means that some functionality continues working even if the user goes offline. I find some programmers use AJAX for things which don't reallly require communication with the server at all.

When using this technique, if possible, I find it helpful to embed *all* the data which the front-end Javascript may need in the page, so it doesn't have to go back and request more data from the server using an AJAX call. (In general, whenever data is being communicated over a high-latency channel, you want to send it in big chunks so the client doesn't have to keep constantly coming back for more. The same applies to DB queries: you can often increase performance by pulling back all the data you *might* need with a single query, rather than making numerous fine-grained queries. Even if you don't end up using all of that data, performance will still usually be better.)

One caution: unless you are very disciplined to keep things organized, Javascript which updates the UI by dynamically generating HTML in response to user actions can become very hairy. If the Javascript is also dynamically generated using another language (running on the server side), things can get downright frightening.

Testability is also important in any app. If you are using something like Selenium, testing a combination client/server web app may not be a problem, but if you aren't, testing server-side code may be easier.

As others have noted, you must also make sure that you don't compromise security. Don't expect that people will only invoke your server-side code in the way you provide for. View all the types of requests your server handles as forming an "API" which people may invoke with any arguments and in any order.

Comment: +1 for the second paragraph :)

Answer (score 1):

String manipulation is pretty fast in the server side but it's fine to do on the client side too. However make sure to validate the string once it arrives at the server side because any client can replicate requests to your server with a string and try to cause trouble.

Answer (score 0):

You must take into consideration a lot of factors, including and especially security ones. For example, if you must do some complicated form validation, then it is extremely important to do it server-side, even if that puts a little more load on the server.

Always keep in mind that a bad guy can change/break your javascript and send invalid (or possibly malicious) data to the server.

When it comes to web programming, the single and most important rule of all is:

**Never trust the user. With anything. Period.**

In your case (with the String), you probably can do it client-side and verify on the server that it's ok.

Answer (score 0):

I am a django/python developer and my logic is "templates should be used for rendering". I keep my load minimum on the client side and all computation is done on the server side.

Another reason for doing this is because a user cannot be trusted. Keep the equation simple for the user.

Comment: you cant trust the user but you can surely trust django, it does sanitize all the user inputs :)

Comment: trust in regards to erroneous or malicious input. And do remember the fact django is opensource, new release might might might have loop holes :)